# Docker container is running json-server but browser says page isn't working

Tags: docker, json-server

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.18.1-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT \["npm", "start"\]
```

and in my package.json here is the start script

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "json-server --watch db.json"
},
```

and here is a screenshot of docker logs

[Docker logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR315.png)

browser screenshot running at localhost:3000

[Browser running at localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxs69.png)

It should serve my db.json file with this data

```
{
"currency" : \[
{
"id": 1,
"rate": 117,
"value": "usd",
"currency": "USD",
"selected": true
}
\]
}
```

Comment: I hope you are mapping the host port while running Docker image e.g. `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name <container-name> <image-name>`

Comment: @GauravPathak Yes am mapping the port. But for some reason the data isn't accessible

Comment: How are you running the container?  What is its output?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  You can [edit] the question to include the plain-text container logs.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some few things in the docker file and it worked.

```
FROM node:16.18.1-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install -g json-server
COPY . /app
CMD json-server --watch /app/db.json --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0
```